# Sencha Touch -- Put JSON variable into Data Store?

Tags: jquery, json, sencha-touch

I have a variable with JSON in it (it's a variable because I got it using JQuery from a local file...offline, so this was necessary). Anyway, how do I get it so this is seen as a JSON inside of a store?

I tried the following, but it doesn't load.

```
// jData is the variable with the JSON
var jData = loadJSON("sampledata.json");


Ext.regModel('myStore', {
fields: [
        {name:"Name",type:"string"},
        {name:"id",type:"int"}
        ]
});


var myStore = new Ext.data.Store({
model: 'myStore',
autoLoad: true,
 proxy: {
    data: jData,
    reader: {
        type: 'json'
    }
}});
```

JSON looks like:
   [{"Name": "High", "id": 1},{"Name": "Medium", "id": 2},{"Name": "Low", "id": 3}]

I am building an Android app and upon using:

```
alert(jData);
```

I receive the JSON perfectly, but can't figure out how to get it into the Store to be used in a selectfield

Comment: Where does jQuery come into it? Is loadJSON using jQuery rather than Ext?

Comment: yes, the loadJSON is using jQuery as this is purely an offline app so using an ajax request doesn't work and the only workaround I could find was in jQuery.

Comment: Dont forget to mark accepted answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this. The simplest way is:

```
// jData is the variable with the JSON
var jData = loadJSON("sampledata.json");


Ext.regModel('myStore', {
fields: [
        {name:"Name",type:"string"},
        {name:"id",type:"int"}
        ]
});


var myStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'myStore',
    data: jData
});
```

If this does not work try this:

```
// jData is the variable with the JSON
var jData = loadJSON("sampledata.json");


Ext.regModel('myStore', {
fields: [
        {name:"Name",type:"string"},
        {name:"id",type:"int"}
        ]
});


var myStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'myStore',
    autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'sampledata.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            }
    }

});
```

Also see: [this](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store)